# Magento Invoice auto email not sent

Tags: magento, invoice

Magento 1.9 Community version. I enable invoicing in the system configuration but when a customer purchases a item (virtual) the new order email goes out but not the invoice. Am I missing something?

Comment: Some work done I read the following sites ([site used as sample code](http://www.brainre.org/magento-automatically-send-invoice-email-after-invoice-is-created/)) and mimic the process on creating an observer to email me the invoice. but I am getting the following error: **Warning: get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, boolean given in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php on line 1340** `ray`

Answer (score -1):

When you ask magento to invoice you order you need to check near the butto "Send copy of mail"

Comment: Hi Guerra, this is what I have done System->Sales Emails ->Invoice->Enabled->Yes.  I want the invoice to be sent at the time the order and credit card is process. All my products are virtual. But the system is not sending it.

Answer (score -3):

The sample code works in magento 1.9 [sample code](http://www.brainre.org/magento-automatically-send-invoice-email-after-invoice-is-created/)
The problem was that I had compilation enabled which did not allowed for any of changes to the code to take place.

Comment: link gives 404. perfect example of an answer who's validity relies on an external link. will remove downvote if you can post the code sample